# Add text to top of grid in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which, when plotted looks like this:

```
ggplot(melted.genes, aes(x=Index.SNP, y=value, fill = variable, color=variable)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=12) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan4", 'yellow'))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","black")) +
  ylab("Probability") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.5, color="red", linetype='dashed')+
  theme(text=element_text(size=23),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

I want to plot the `Gene` column that I want plotted at the very top of the plot.

Can't seem to find the answer on stack, how do I do this?

```
> dput(melted.genes)
structure(list(Index.SNP = c("rs6461561", "rs9926049", "rs6479487", 
"rs7432375", "rs2304205", "rs144821294", "rs35045093", "rs10777187", 
"rs61786047", "rs11062162", "rs2224086", "rs6461561", "rs9926049", 
"rs6479487", "rs7432375", "rs2304205", "rs144821294", "rs35045093", 
"rs107771865", "rs61786047", "rs11062162", "rs2224086"), Gene = c("SP4", 
"GRIN2A", "FAM120A", "STAG1", "SCAF1", "AP3D1", "PAX4", "ATP2B1", 
"GMEB1", "CACNA1C", "CSDE1", "SP4", "GRIN2A", "FAM120A", "STAG1", 
"SCAF1", "AP3D1", "PAX4", "ATP2B1", "GMEB1", "CACNA1C", "CSDE1"
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("PANs.Score.Proportion", 
"MAGMA.Score.Proportion"), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 1, 
1, 0.76, 0.08, 0.96, 0, 0.98, 0, 1, 0.98, 0.92, 1, 0.35, 0.19, 
0.18, 0.21, 0.17, 0.14, 0.1, 1, 0.26)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: which column are you wanting at the top of the graph?

Comment: sorry, the `Gene` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add your `Gene` column to the top of the plot via a secondary or duplicated x axis. To this end we have to use a continuous scale which requires to convert `Index.SNP` to a numeric and set the labels manually using the `labels` argument of `scale_x_continuous`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

melted.genes <- melted.genes |>
  mutate(index_snp_num = as.numeric(factor(Index.SNP)))

xlabels1 <- melted.genes |>
  distinct(index_snp_num, Index.SNP) |>
  tibble::deframe()

xlabels2 <- melted.genes |>
  distinct(index_snp_num, Gene) |>
  tibble::deframe()

xbreaks <- unique(melted.genes$index_snp_num)

ggplot(melted.genes, aes(x = index_snp_num, y = value, fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 12) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan4", "yellow")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black")) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = xbreaks, labels = xlabels1,
    sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = xlabels2, name = NULL)
  ) +
  ylab("Probability") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 23),
    axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0)
  )
```

[image]